# Stereo-Mono circuit after passive bandpass filter

Tags: resistors, filter, stereo

If i put a passive RC band pass (high pass + low pass) filter before the amplifer and right next to it I sum the channels with 1-5 k ohm resistors, then the amplifier is turned on,is there a possibility that those summing resistors could act as a filter prolongation?

Filrer:

[image]

Summing (witch is right after filter)

[image]

Resistor values will be 1 - 5 kohm

Comment: Why don't you include a schematic of what you propose, that would make this much easier to answer.

Comment: In any case, you must be aware that those summing resistors heavily will influence (destroy) the filter respose - unless you are using two buffer amplifiers in between.

Comment: But if i use summing resistors in speaker side - after amp, will it change something? or maybe I can make summing cable, so it is before filter?

Comment: Closing until the handwaving is replaced by a schematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The low input impedance of the summing stage will affect the filter response. To fix this without additional components such as a buffer, you can sum the signals before the filter (and then use only one filter).

Just select R1a and R1b such that the [thevenin equivalent resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem) (the parallel combination) is the same as R1 that you desired for the filter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH5O2c.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This is fallacious. R1a and R1b aren't in parallel. Each source will see either R1a or R1b, not both. The filter calculation doesn't involve them both. The place to put the summing resistors is after the shunt leg of the filter, where it just becomes part of the presumably high I out impedance of the following amplifier.

Comment: No. It is not about what the sources see. The filter response is determined by the impedance R1. By combining the sources before it is equivalent to a single source. After the filter, summing resistors introduce load not because of the amplifier's input but rather because of the other summing resistor.

Comment: Using online calculator, i get these values: R1a and R1b - 100 ohm, R2 - 100 ohm, C1 - 100 Uf, C2 - 10 Uf. That gives 80 hz low pass and 16 hz high pass frekv. Is this correct?

Comment: @EJP: No, R1a and R1b *are* in parallel for the purpose of computing the resistance working against C1 to form the high pass filter.  I suggest you undo your downvote, and +1 from me.